# Index, fkey(constriant), and column in PGAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very new with SQL, I'm running through PGAdmin. I have a column that is primary language and in its SQL Pane it says

```
-- ALTER TABLE table name DROP COLUMN primary_language

ALTER TABLE table name ADD COLUMN primary_language integer;
```

So I'm receiving an integer rather than the language. 
There is also an index and an fkey, all associated with the primary language. Am I missing a step in order to receive the language rather than the integer? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `--` means that line was commented out. language is not a data type; integer is. There most likely is a `language` tabel somewhere, which will have an `id` column you can use to look up what language corresponds to what number

Answer (score 0):

The -- means that line was commented out. language is not a data type; integer is. There most likely is a language tabel somewhere, which will have an id column you can use to look up what language corresponds to what number.

You could query the language table and combine it with your current table by means of a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    MyTable
INNER JOIN language 
    ON MyTable.primary_language = language.id
```

You might have to change the table and column names for that to work, but as we do not know your database schema, it's impossible to provide you with a working piece of code.